# YII2: Gii. Генерация CRUD из двух таблиц БД с отношениями

Tags: yii2, crud, gii

**Возможно ли с помощью Gii сгенерировать CRUD из таблиц БД с отношениями?**

Пример таблиц:

**author**

```
id
name              // имя автора
```

**book**

```
id 
title            // название книги
author_id       // id автора из таблицы author
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE author (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE book (
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    author_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_book_author`
        FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Gii генерирует метод в модели Author метод getBooks()

```
   public function getBooks()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Book::className(), ['author_id' => 'id']);
   }
```

Я правильно понимаю, что с помощью этого метода можно во view вывести книги автора? (если нет, можно ссылку на пример)

И второй вопрос: Как из этой структуры таблиц БД в YII2 создать CRUD, чтобы при добавлении книги можно было выбрать вместо author_id - имя автора. Я имею ввиду автоматизированные способы (если такие существуют), чтобы он из relation понял, что нужно сгенерировать на основе отношений модель и CRUD.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вы хотите сразу две модели сгенерировать со связями? Стандартный функционал, если не брать сторонних расширенных крудов, предлагает ставить связи при генерации модели по внешним ключам таблиц в базе данных.

Comment: Модели вручную, а CRUD на основе этих двух моделей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я правильно понимаю, что с помощью этого метода можно во view вывести
>   книги автора?

Да, можно вывести все данных книг c помощью переменной `$model->books` через  `foreach`, где `$model` это модель `Author`

> Как из этой структуры таблиц БД в YII2 создать CRUD, чтобы при
>   добавлении книги можно было выбрать вместо author_id - имя автора.

Через `relation` это сделать нельзя, потому что связи ещё нет, вы же только создаёте книгу. Поэтому это делается так:

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Book();
    $authors = Author::find()->all();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'authors' => $authors
        ]);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

<?= $form->field($model, 'author_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($authors, 'id', 'name'))->label('Выберите имя автора'); ?>
```